# Можно ли в Java создать алиас для уже существующего типа?

Tags: java

В приведённом ниже коде не очевидно, что является ключом в Map:

```java
public abstract class TasksRetrievingGateway {
  public abstract Map<String, Task> getAllTasks();
}
```

В TypeScript можно можно внести ясность, создав алиас для типа `string`:

```
type TaskID = string;

public abstract class TasksRetrievingGateway {
  public abstract getAllTasks(): Map<TaskID, Task>;
}
```

Есть ли подобный механизм в Java?

Comment: `не очевидно, что является ключом в Map` ... `Map<String, Task>`  - тут ключем является строка, очевидно же. Если вам надо использовать свой тип - вам придется создать свой класс для этого.

Comment: Как раз таки вариант как в TS не очевиден ибо нужно искать где объявлен реальный тип. А если в проекте 100500+ файлов? Не сравнивайте Java (изначально строготипизированный язык) и TS (иммтация типизации).

Comment: @Tsyklop `Ctrl+B` в IntelliJ IDEA мигом отправит на место объявления типа. В других мало-мальски популярных IDE такой функционал тоже есть.

Comment: @БоковГлеб Без IDE попишите код.

Comment: @Tsyklop, ну уж нет, с таким же успехом можно попробовать заняться ручной работой вместо конвейерного производства в машиностроении. В качестве развлечения поначалу и весело, но с точки зрения эффективности и производительности - пустая трата времени.

Comment: @tym32167, я имею ввиду "семантически неочевидно". Другими словами, зная что ключом является строка, мы по `Map<String, Task>` не можем сказать, какую информацию строка в себе несёт. Например, у Task есть ID и имя ("name"), причём и ID и имя уникальные. Тогда, на месте ключа `Map<String, Task>` могут быть как ID, так и уникальное имя, а может и ещё что-то. В TypeScript эту неопределённость можно убрать, создав алиас для типа "string". Тогда, вместо `Map<String, Task>` будет `Map<TaskID, Task>` или `Map<TaskName, Task>`. Вопрос этот о том, возможно ли сделать то же самое в Java.

Comment: Я уже ответил, что алиасов в java нет, если надо указать специфический тип - придется написать для этого класс. Неопределенность, о которой вы говорите в java или c# решается своими классами и/или контекстом (названиями переменных, методов и т.д.). Это не уникальная проблема, решение алиасами которой требуется видимо только в TS (хотя я и в TS алиасы никогда не использовал за ненадобностью)